# I have a dataframe df and I want to draw a radial bar/column chart with the values mapped against the cities

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataframe df and I want to draw a radial bar/column chart with the values mapped against the cities.

The dataframe looks like:

| City | Counts |
| --- | --- |
| Leeds | 5 |
| Liverpool | 7 |
| Birmingham | 8 |
| Nottingham | 14 |

I am able to get the horizontal bar chart but not the radial one

```
colors = ["red","green","blue","yellow","magenta","cyan"]
plt.barh("state", "counts", data = m, color = colors)
plt.xlabel("Number of Firearm Incidents per head")
plt.ylabel("LSOA Region")
plt.title("Firearm Incidents vs LSOA per head")
plt.show()
```

I want something like these two
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXDow.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIArH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible approach:

```
# import pandas for data wrangling
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Build a dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['Leeds', 'Liverpool', 'Birmingham', 'Nottingham'],
                   'Counts': [5, 7, 8, 14]})

# Reorder the dataframe
df = df.sort_values(by=['Counts'])

# initialize the figure
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
plt.axis('off')

# Constants = parameters controling the plot layout:
upperLimit = 100
lowerLimit = 30
labelPadding = 4

# Compute max and min in the dataset
max = df['Counts'].max()

# Let's compute heights: they are a conversion of each item value in those new coordinates
# In our example, 0 in the dataset will be converted to the lowerLimit (10)
# The maximum will be converted to the upperLimit (100)
slope = (max - lowerLimit) / max
heights = slope * df.Counts + lowerLimit

# Compute the width of each bar. In total we have 2*Pi = 360°
width = 2*np.pi / len(df.index)

# Compute the angle each bar is centered on:
indexes = list(range(1, len(df.index)+1))
angles = [element * width for element in indexes]
angles

# Draw bars
bars = ax.bar(
    x=angles, 
    height=heights, 
    width=width, 
    bottom=lowerLimit,
    linewidth=2, 
    edgecolor="white",
    color="#61a4b2",
)

# Add labels
for bar, angle, height, label in zip(bars,angles, heights, df["City"]):

    # Labels are rotated. Rotation must be specified in degrees :(
    rotation = np.rad2deg(angle)

    # Flip some labels upside down
    alignment = ""
    if angle >= np.pi/2 and angle < 3*np.pi/2:
        alignment = "right"
        rotation = rotation + 180
    else: 
        alignment = "left"

    # Finally add the labels
    ax.text(
        x=angle, 
        y=lowerLimit + bar.get_height() + labelPadding, 
        s=label, 
        ha=alignment, 
        va='center', 
        rotation=rotation, 
        rotation_mode="anchor")
```

Comment: Tried this however it is generating an error "shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape" in here "bars = ax.bar(
    x=angles, 
    height=heights, 
    width=width, 
    bottom=lowerLimit,
    linewidth=2, 
    edgecolor="white",
    color="#61a4b2",
)"

Comment: Your data frame might have `null` or non-numeric values in the `Counts` column. Have you checked this possibility? Also, you can try to increase the `upperLimit` to something bigger than 100.

Comment: I have just taken 5 numeric values in the counts column dataframe which are not null. Also I have plotted plotted a horizontal bar which is working fine. I have also increased the upper limit to 200 but the problems persists.

Comment: Try running the exact code above at https://colab.research.google.com/ to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot finally it worked. Could you tell me how to change its colours?

Comment: I'm happy it was helpful! Please, accept my answer above with the checkmark. To change the colors you can, for example, change `color="#61a4b2"` to another HEX (https://www.google.com/search?q=hex+color) like `color="#16e05a"`.